# TextView & StringArray misfunction

Tags: android, textview

Well i made an activity where i am creating some TextViews based on the size of a string array! But despite the fact that my string array has 4 items on it, which i tested it with debugging, the textviews that are created is only 1. If anyone has an idea about it please tell me :)

```
setContentView(R.layout.program);

    String[] daily_lessons = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.firstGradeLessons);
    final TextView[] tv = new TextView[daily_lessons.length];
    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
    fasa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    fasa.setText(String.valueOf(daily_lessons.length));


    for (int i=0; i<daily_lessons.length; i++){
        tv[i] = new TextView(this);
        tv[i].setText(daily_lessons[i]);
        tv[i].setTextSize(20);
        tv[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,(int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(tv[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I think your textview creation may be working fine but they are all getting stack on each other.

Comment: Try to put some top margin in the for loop or may be assign same weight to all of them in for loop. so that they will show up.

Comment: Well i tried the top Margin but they still seem to be stacked on!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still need an answer to this question here is what I would do.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.program);

    String[] daily_lessons = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.firstGradeLessons);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
    fasa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    fasa.setText(String.valueOf(daily_lessons.length));

    TextView tmpView = null;
    for (int i=0; i<daily_lessons.length; i++){
        tmpView = new TextView(this);
        tmpView.setText(daily_lessons[i]);
        tmpView.setTextSize(20);
        layout.addView(tmpView , new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
```

I use this type of code alot for my dynamically genenerated content (obtain content from prepopulated database).

Comment: Thnx for answering but it passed a long time and my app has really changed a lot. So i wont make use of your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

The TextView seems to be created but might now be visible on the GUI may be stacked over each other etc.

1.Use the **layout.setOrientation(ORIENTAIION.VERTICAL)** on the parent linear layout's.

2.Use the **childCount()** on layout to make it sure on the fact that the all 4 text views have been added to the snippet.

3.Also make sure your are not using **removeALLView()** etc methods for your case study to the problem case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Some questions. How do i use childCount? I am not using any removeAllView() function for sure!

Comment: Also the parent Linear Layout has vertical Orientation

Comment: apart from root your parent findViewById(R.id.linear1) also have this set.  Also getChildCount is used to return the child count of any viewgroup (say linear layout)

Comment: Well tried all that is mentioned here and still no luck! I dont know what the getChildCount is supposed to do but i am going to try it

Comment: it does to give you the exact number of items that it posses( say texView items in your case).

Comment: So i will use it after the for loop?

Comment: Well i used it and it printed 4! So it's the correct number based on my StringArray! But the text views arent printed!